# Sublime Text 3 Sublimelinter phplint and php not found?

Tags: php, sublimetext3, lint, sublimelinter

I have been playing with this for over an hour to get the sublimelinter working.

So I now have the following packages installed:

- `SublimeLinter`
- `SublimeLinter-php`
- `SublimeLinter-phplint`

Does someone know why it still does not lint the PHP I write?

I am working on Windows and cannot find any docs relating to sublime 3 and windows.

The console reads:

```
SublimeLinter: cannot locate 'phplint' 

SublimeLinter: cannot locate 'php'
```

Comment: This is not about programming

Comment: This is, however, very much about [a software tool commonly used by programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which is on-topic. I feel this question is specific, objective (non-subjective), answerable _on this site_, and useful.

Comment: -1 is a bit harsh for a question in scope of the website? Thanks you for your input @acheong87

Comment: Perfectly good question and I'm sure it will help many people. I was struggling with this for ages and was missing the sublimelinter-php package noted above

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I had the same problem and FINALLY figured out, how to get SublimeLinter to work in SublimeText 3. After installing `SublimeLinter` and `SublimeLinter-php` it kept telling me `SublimeLinter: cannot locate 'php'`. (No surprise, PHP isn't in my `PATH` on purpose).

After adding the path of my PHP installation to the SublimeLinter User Settings (Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeLinter -> Settings - User), and a restart of SublimeText everything is working as expected now.

Here is the relevant part:

```
"paths": {
    "linux": [],
    "osx": [],
    "windows": [
        "C:/Program Files (x86)/PHP/php-5.4/"
    ]
},
```

I didn't have to change anything else.

Comment: ST 3 showed a parsing error (Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in...) with the above copy/pasted into my user settings.  I removed the empty linux and osx values and it saved without errors.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: +1 Under windows, even with the php.exe path configured in the windows PATH variable I needed to put it too in the linter configuration.

Comment: @wolfstevent: I just looked at my settings file again. There are indeed a couple of brackets that I seem to have either forgotten or that got added later. I edited my original answer. It should work now.

Comment: still say "no lint error" ..no linting even settings are fixed

Comment: This helped, even with using OSX! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I encountered the same issue on Windows with the [SublimeLinter-php](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-php) independent linter plugin for the widely rewritten [SublimeLinter 3](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3):

> WARNING: php deactivated, cannot locate 'php'

I solved it too by just adding the relevant `PATH` (with double backslashes!) in SublimeLinter 3 "extra pathes" user setting (vs. other method/choice i.e. directly editing the Windows `PATH` environment variable), so that the **executable’s directory** is available to SublimeLinter:

```
"paths": {
    "linux": [],
    "osx": [],
    "windows": [
    "C:\\xampplite\\php\\"
    ]
}
```

It's really worth noting that you must provide the directory that will be searched, **not the direct path to the executable**; it took me a while to figure this out, since the corresponding SublimeLinter setting in Sublime Text 2 must on the contrary include the executable; in my case:

```
"sublimelinter_executable_map":
{
    "php": "C:\\xampplite\\php\\php.exe"
}
```

Comment: I just want to emphasize the fact about double backslashes in the path of Windows, therefore C:\\, not C://. That was the reason I struggled. Thanks Erwan

Answer (score 5):

I was struggling with this as well but just got it working.
You need to install phplint which you can download from http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/download.html

Open up the zip and copy phplint.exe and phpl.bat to your php directory (mine is c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/)

You also need to have the path to php in your windows path which you can find by right clicking on 'my computer' and properties -> advanced system settings -> environment variables -> system variables -> path
Add the path on the end separated by a ; mine was as above C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13 if you want to use node for js hinting then add the path to node here as well.

I think the linters now get added automatically but you can check in the file:

Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeLinter -> Settings - User

Mine looks like this (the relevant parts. If the file is blank copy the contents of the default settings file)

```
"lint_mode": "background",
    "linters": {
        "csslint": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "errors": "",
            "excludes": [],
            "ignore": "",
            "warnings": ""
        },
        "htmltidy": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "excludes": []
        },
        "jshint": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "excludes": []
        },
        "php": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "excludes": []
        },
        "phplint": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "excludes": []
        }
    },
    "mark_style": "outline",
```

If you then restart it should start linting.

Comment: I can't find any phplint.exe in the archives I've downloaded nor in the cvs repository, are you sure about that ?

Answer (score 2):

**step 1**: Find out the location of php executable (use cmd 'which php' on linux) => "/usr/bin/php"
**step 2**: Edit the Subimelinter package's user settings with the following steps.
**step 3**: Edit the linters object related to php with this `"linters": {
            "php": {
                "@disable": false,
                "args": [],
                "cmd": "/usr/bin/php",
                "excludes": []
            }
        },`

**step 4**: Make sure the syntax_map object has "php": "php" like this `"syntax_map": {
            "html (django)": "html",
            "html (rails)": "html",
            "html 5": "html",
            "javascript (babel)": "javascript",
            "javascript (dom)": "javascript",
            "magicpython": "python",
            "php": "php",
            "python django": "python",
            "pythonimproved": "python"
        },`

Note: Before following all these steps make sure that you have installed both sublimeter, and sublimelinter-php packages.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up reading the entire documentation and found that during install the links provided where quite substantial and it had only been due to my speed of reading I had not seen all the information I have needed.

For future reference I used:
Find a suitable linter: https://github.com/SublimeLinter

To fix lint issues: http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#debugging-path-problems

For PHP lib: http://windows.php.net/download/

Path Editor (I went down this route): http://patheditor2.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

SublimeLinter3 was just released, and is a complete rewrite of the old version. I haven't had a chance to completely parse them yet, but the new docs are located [here](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter.github.io/wiki). I'd urge you to read through them completely, as the architecture has changed dramatically, and the settings are quite different from before.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo, I have looked through the documentation and while a lot of it seems very thorough I could not find any information about actually hooking up the linter.